# PHP code unable to connect to mysql server

Tags: php

```
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');


use React\EventLoop\Factory;
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream;
use Devristo\Phpws\Client\WebSocket;

$loop = Factory::create();

$logger = new Logger();
$writer = new Stream("php://output");
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$client = new WebSocket("wss://dev2.alphapoint.com:8402/v1/GetRealTime/", $loop, $logger);

$client->on("request", function($headers) use ($logger){
    $logger->notice("Request object created!");
});

$client->on("handshake", function() use ($logger) {
    $logger->notice("Handshake received!");
});

$client->on("connect", function($headers ='') use ($logger, $client){
    $logger->notice("Connected!");
    $client->send('{"messageType":"subscribeFromIndex","StartIndex":2,"ProductPair":"BTCAUD"}');
});

$client->on("message", function($message) use ($client, $logger){
    echo "messge accepted";
    $str =$message->getData();
    $logger->notice("Got message: ".$str);    
    $client->close();

    if(!empty($str)) {
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password', 'dbname', 3306);                       

        $items =json_decode($str)->items;
        //print_r($items);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        foreach($items as $i) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO data_web (time, open, high, low, close, volume) VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ($i[0]/1000)).'\', '.$i[1].', '.$i[2].', '.$i[3].', '.$i[4].', '.$i[5].");\n";
            echo $query;
            mysqli_query($link, $query);
        }

        /* close connection */
        mysqli_close($link);

    }
});

$client->open();
$loop->run();
```

I am having some problem running the php code. When I  run `php index.php` and it just stuck on connected and never insert data to mysql.

This is what it shows below:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\php-graph-code\aws\aws>php index.php
2016-04-08T03:33:28-04:00 NOTICE (5): Request object created!
2016-04-08T03:33:29-04:00 NOTICE (5): Handshake received!
2016-04-08T03:33:29-04:00 NOTICE (5): Connected!
```

All dependencies are there, MYSQL has been tested to work.

Comment: Is it supposed to be receiving a message?

Comment: You've got inadequate mysqli error checking.  These methods can all fail and as such errors need to be handled properly.  mysqli_connect returns false if it couldn't connect, so use that to check for connection failure.  This is also true for mysqli_query.  It will return false if the query you tried to execute failed, but you're not doing any checking for this.  You should compare the return from mysqli_query with false and use mysqli_errno and mysqli_error to determine what went wrong if it does return false.  Once you've added better error detection the problem should become obvious.